# QML Listview anchor

Tags: c++, qml, qlistview

I have a messenger and i want my messages be at the right and client messages at the left. Messages are added to a listview.

```
ListView {
            id: listview
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: messageModel
            delegate: ItemDelegate
            {
                text: model.message
                checked: true
                font.family: "Comic Sans MS"
                font.pixelSize: 15
                anchors.right: parent.right
            }
        }
```

So my messages are at right.

```
           TextField {
                id: textField
                Material.accent: Material.Purple
                font.family: "Comic Sans MS"
                Layout.fillWidth: true; Layout.fillHeight: true
                placeholderText: "Write a message..."
                background: null
                focus: true
                Keys.onPressed: {
                    if (event.key == Qt.Key_Enter && textField.text != "") {
                        listview.anchors.right = parent.right
                        messageModel.append({message: textField.text});
                        textField.text = ""
                        listview.positionViewAtEnd()
                    }
                }
            }
```

listview.anchors won't do anything why?

Answer (score 0):

Anchor the delegate to its parent. For example:

```js
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: 10
    spacing: 2
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement { target: 1; message: "message1" }
        ListElement { target: 1; message: "messageeeee2" }
        ListElement { target: 2; message: "messageee3" }
        ListElement { target: 2; message: "messageeeeeeeeeeee4" }
        ListElement { target: 1; message: "messageeeeee5" }
    }
    delegate: Rectangle {
        height: 30
        width: txt.width + 10
        anchors.right: target == 1 ? undefined : parent.right
        anchors.left: target == 2 ? undefined : parent.left
        radius: 5
        border {
            width: 2
            color: "orange"
        }
        Text {
            id: txt
            text: message
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i know - but what if i want to access anchors. from out of the delegate?

Comment: The Code above! I want to access Listview in the if clause.

Comment: Sorry, I see no attempt to access `ListView` in your code. Anyway, you can use [ListView.view](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#view-attached-prop)

Comment: There is no attempt because i don't know how to do it. I've added a comment. That where i want to access listveiw and i don't know how! Somthing like : @listview.anchors.right = parent.right@ but won't work!

Comment: You always can access an item by its `id`. if that doesn't work the reason is that `listview` is out of scope. But you should provide mcve, now it's unclear from where do you call this code.

Comment: Okay - take a look at code now. it won't place the text on the right. why?